# strip_tags crashes for big value

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, strip-tags

i am using strip_tags to strip the tags from xml file and it works just fine when the array size is small but if the page is big it crashes always.here is my script which works for upto 100 values but crashes for bigger value

```
        preg_match_all("/<image:caption>.*?<\/image:caption>|<image:loc>.*?<\/image:loc>|<loc>.*?<\/loc>/", $str, $results);
         $arr = array_chunk(array_map('strip_tags', $results[0]), 1000);

        for($i=0;$i < 1000;$i++){
      for($j=0;$j < 1000;$j++){


      $output=$arr[$i][$j]. '</br>';


      echo $output;
        }

        }
```

it will strip these values nicely but for bigger file it crashes.

```
      <urlset>

        <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/228615/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Cabrio Auto Car Wallshark Com  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>

          <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/213157/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Cars Citro N Cabrio  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>

          <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/95569/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Citro N Pictures  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>
        </urlset>
```

Comment: Why exactly are you parsing XML with regexes? Use an XML parser instead!

Comment: @ThiefMaster which one will be faster

Comment: @ThiefMaster its remote file and i dont think we can parse remote files

Comment: Your code looks strange, what are your trying to do exactly? Please, can you post your desired output?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i have to insert the values of loc,image caption and image src for each set in database

Comment: @user3026718: Ok, so for each <url> tags you must extract the 3 values, and i suppose that there are a column for loc, a column for image:loc and a column for caption in your database?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte exactly

Comment: @user3026718: so you don't need to modify the source file, but only to extract datas?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<pre><?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->load('Remotefile.xml');

$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('url');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $image = $url->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0);
    $imageChildren = $image->childNodes;

    $result[] = array( 'loc' => $url->getElementsByTagName('loc')->item(0)->textContent,
                       'imgloc' => $imageChildren->item(0)->textContent,
                       'imgcap' => $imageChildren->item(1)->textContent);
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO urls (loc, imageloc, imagecap) VALUES (:loc, :imgloc, :imgcap)");

foreach ($result as $res) {
    $stmt -> bindParam(':loc',    $res['loc']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':imgloc', $res['imgloc']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':imgcap', $res['imgcap']);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

A regex way:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
  <url>                                                \s*+
  <loc>           (?<loc>    [^<]++ ) </loc>           \s*+
  <image:image>                                        \s*+
  <image:loc>     (?<imgloc> [^<]++ ) </image:loc>     \s*+
  <image:caption> (?<imgcap> [^<]++ ) </image:caption> \s*+
  </image:image>                                       \s*+
  </url>
~x
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

/* this foreach part is only for cosmetic and is totally useless */
foreach($matches as &$match) {
    foreach($match as $k=>$m) {
        if (is_numeric($k)) unset($match[$k]);
    }
}
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Fatal error:  Call to a member function item() on a non-object in

Comment: @user3026718: Does your file contains url tags without image or loc tags inside? or part with a different structure than your example?

Comment: @user3026718: It works for me. check the return of `$dom->load(..` with `var_dump(@dom->load(...));` (replace the line)

Comment: can u give any live example.its not working bool(true)


Fatal error:  Call to a member function item()